# Accessing session data in controller(Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-variables, session-state

I have a page 'A'. I create a session variable on this page.

This page is then redirected to a function 'A' in a controller 'A' using `window.location`.

I try to access the session variable in the function 'A' using the following line

```
var_dump($request->session->get('variableSetOnPageA'));
```

This returns `NULL`.

Why? I need the 'variableSetOnPageA'.

Comment: Please show us the actual code. (All relevant code, not just one single line that doesn't tell us much about what's going on).

Comment: you are not actually setting a session variable, simple

Answer (score 10):

You can also get `Session` variable in Laravel like below in any of your function in Controller file:

```
$value = Session::get('variableSetOnPageA');
```

And you can set your `Session` variable like below in any of your function:

```
$variableSetOnPageA = "Can be anything";
Session::put('variableSetOnPageA',$variableSetOnPageA);
```

In your Controller file, make sure you add below code at top:

```
use Session;
```

Comment: we can also use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;` instead of `use Session;`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You ought to invoke the `session` method from [\Illuminate\Http\Request](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html):

```
$request->session()->get('foo')
```

or global helper function

```
session('foo')
```

Comment: i used this.I get NULL

Answer (score 0):

Important: It is very important that you call `save` function after you set any session value like this:

```
$request->session()->put('any-key', 'value');
$request->session()->save();    // This will actually store the value in session and it will be available then all over.
```

Check if you have $request available in the function.

```
public function A(Request $request)  // Notice Request $request here.
{
    $value = $request->session()->get('your-key');

    //
}
```

Comment: they would be getting an undefined variable error if they didn't have `$request` ... the `StartSession` middleware calls `save` if needed on the session driver after the response has been returned, as long the lifecycle makes it that far that is

Comment: @lagbox, Actually I had the exactly same issue with Laravel 5.4 and by calling `$request->session()->save();` I got it solved.

Comment: I'm not using  $request->session->put('key','value').

Comment: On page 'A', i use $_SESSION['key'] = 'value'.

Comment: Then in the controller I simply use $request->session->get('key').Also $request is declared in the parameter list

Comment: No @ZainUlAbideen, don't do in that way. Use `$request->session()->put('any-key', 'value');
$request->session()->save();` and then try to get it as you are doing. I am sure it will work. Just give it a try my answer.

Comment: I cannot use $request in my view file.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen, in your view, access session value like this: `{{ Session::get('bookingConfirmed') }}`

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen, please give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Any luck @ZainUlAbideen?

Answer (score 0):

This might be help you

```
if (session()->has('variableSetOnPageA')) {
  $result=session()->get('variableSetOnPageA')
}
```

Comment: The problem is I'm getting a NULL while using $request->session->get('key').I need the value that I stored in the session on page 'A'.